# Improve responsiveness of resizing & panning imshow/countourf/pcolormesh?

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I have the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 4)

for ax in axes.ravel():
    ax.imshow(np.random.rand(30, 30))
    
plt.show()
```

It's simple and yet I find on my system that resizing the figure is dramatically slow (1-2 fps). It's only managing 8 30 x 30 arrays so I'm a bit surprised. I've haven't even used additional feature calls & features like `sharex=True`, `sharey=True`, `constrained_layout=True`, **plt.colorbar()** etc but even with all these disabled, the above example pans and zooms very slowly.

Is there a convenient way to improve this? I'm trying to embed such a figure into a tk GUI and resizing the combination of the two is just completely un-manageable. I get similar results with **pcolormesh** and **countourf** and have tried setting `interpolation='nearest'` options.

Even the blitting example refreshed very quickly for me in static position so my issue is more consistent with the resizing and less so the actual content of the figures or amount of data (I believe).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.animation as animation

def gen(): return(np.random.rand(30, 30))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 4, constrained_layout=True, sharex=True, sharey=True)
images = [ax.imshow(gen()) for ax in axes.ravel()]

def animate(i):
    for im in images:
        im.set_array(gen())
    return(images)

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=10, blit=True) 
plt.show()
```

Comment: The lagging is likely to depend on machine, mine is ok for your example.

Comment: Do you suggest its a hardware limitation then or likely an environment configuration problem. My machine doesn't have a graphics card but it has i9 CPUs. the blitting example runs at like 100 fps anyways.